# How to join two list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

The following code is a small prototype of a big code.I have class `Student` and list of `class`   and two list of class like `lst` and `lstcarrier`     >in one method i am adding `firstname` only in another method iam adding `age` and `lastname`.I want to join two list and need to get 3 results contain full details like `firstname` ,`lasnmae` ,`age` but when i used `Union` it is giving 6 results rather 3 results.How to get 3 results??

```
public class Student
        {
            public string firstname { get; set; }
            public string lasnmae { get; set; }
            public string age { get; set; }
        }

 List<Student> lst = new List<Student>();
            List<Student> lstcarrier = new List<Student>();
            Student st = new Student();
            st.firstname = "sasi";
            lst.Add(st);

            Student st1 = new Student();
            st1.firstname = "rahul";
            lst.Add(st1);

            Student st2 = new Student();
            st2.firstname = "kiran";
            lst.Add(st2);

            Student sc = new Student();
            sc.age = "32";
            sc.lasnmae = "ravi";
            lstcarrier.Add(sc);

            Student sc1 = new Student();
            sc1.age = "33";
            sc1.lasnmae = "mir";
            lstcarrier.Add(sc1);

            Student sc2 = new Student();
            sc2.age = "34";
            sc2.lasnmae = "rar";
            lstcarrier.Add(sc2);

            List<Student> lstfinal = null;
            lstfinal = lst.Union(lstcarrier).ToList() ;
```

Comment: how can this be duplicate??/

Comment: i am not able to do with .Zip

Comment: You can use LINQ to group two lists together based on index. Only condition is both lists needs to have same number of values.  You can do something like  https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8NOg8

Comment: can u post the code for this question??

Comment: check the link in comment

Comment: That is just to display output quickly in dotnetfiddle. Remove it from your own code.